# Access Denied when querying Teams in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Whenever I query the Teams endpoint in Microsoft Graph:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}
```

I get the following error:

```
AccessDenied - Failed to execute Skype backend request GetThreadRequest.
```

The permissions are set according to the documentation. (Group.Read.All - delegated permission)

Querying [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/%7Bguid%7D) is working while with the same access token [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/%7Bguid%7D) isn't.

I tried it with my own application and in the Graph Explorer. Both ways didnt't work for me. However using Graph Explorer with the sample account is working. Is there maybe another permission needed which is not yet documented?

Comment: How did you create this Team? Could you please confirm if team with same id exists using [/joinedTeams](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_joinedteams) Apis? Also, please share the request/resonse?

Comment: Are you a member of the team you are querying, i.e. {id}? Currently that's a requirement.

Comment: Yes it's working for joined teams. Do you know when it's possible to query all teams?

Comment: Could you confirm if you are a member of the team you are querying?

Comment: Yes I tested it and it behaves like you described it. The teams that are listed under /joinedTeams are working for the https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id} request. Quering other teams results in a 403 with the error message posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's a requirement that the person using the Graph APIs (and the PowerShell cmdlets that use them under the covers) must be a member of the team whose information they are trying to retrieve. This is the second-most popular ask for users of our cmdlets, and we are close to resolving it. We expect this to be fixed by the end of September 2018, with write APIs/commands coming a few weeks later than read APIs/commands.