# Failing to get Team details from a c# console app while it works from Graph Explorer

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I need to collect Microsoft Teams data from a C# console application using Microsoft Graph.

I am using ADAL and cloned the authentication methods from the https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-csharp-connect-sample sample.
The only difference is that I am using an *HttpClient* client and not a GraphServiceClient that does not implement Teams objects.
The list of required permissions have been determined with a Fiddler trace of a request made with Graph Explorer (no need for User.Read.All or User.Write.All) :
    `User.Read, Mail.Send, Files.ReadWrite, User.ReadWrite, User.ReadBasic.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All, Contacts.ReadWrite, People.Read, Notes.ReadWrite.All, Tasks.ReadWrite, Mail.ReadWrite, Files.ReadWrite.All, Calendars.ReadWrite`

Everything works fine with my console app as long as I am not requesting any Teams resource:

1. I can get the list of groups "that are Teams" with the following
   request: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/any(v:v eq 'Team')&$select=id,displayname,groupTypes,resourceBehaviorOptions,resourceProvisioningOptions`
2. I can successfully get the group details with: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{groupId}`
3. But when I try to get the team view of that group (which I am member of) it fails with HTTP
   403-Unautorized:
   `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{groupId}/team`
   Very
   frustrating to see that this last step is working well from the
   Graph Explorer

My problem is very similiar with [Access Denied when querying Teams in Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51943098/access-denied-when-querying-teams-in-microsoft-graph) but in my case I am member of the teams I am trying to access and the request works with Graph Explorer.

Code details:

```
class AuthenticationHelper
{
    // The Client ID is used by the application to uniquely identify itself to the v2.0 authentication endpoint.
    static string clientId = Constants.ClientId;

    // The list of required permissions have been determined with a Fiddler trace of a request made with Graph Explorer
    // e.g. below are the permissions Grap Explorer requires to run the sample requests
    public static string[] Scopes = {
              "User.Read"
            , "Mail.Send"
            , "Files.ReadWrite"
            , "User.ReadWrite"
            , "User.ReadBasic.All"
            , "Sites.ReadWrite.All"
            , "Contacts.ReadWrite"
            , "People.Read"
            , "Notes.ReadWrite.All"
            , "Tasks.ReadWrite"
            , "Mail.ReadWrite"
            , "Files.ReadWrite.All"
            , "Calendars.ReadWrite" 
    };

    public static PublicClientApplication IdentityClientApp = new PublicClientApplication(clientId);
    public static string UserToken = null;
    public static DateTimeOffset Expiration;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static async Task<HttpClient> GetAuthenticatedHttpClient()
    {
        HttpClient client = null;
        try
        {
            client= new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseCookies = true });

            var token = await GetTokenForUserAsync();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            // This header has been added to identify our sample in the Microsoft Graph service.  If extracting this code for your project please remove.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SampleID", "TestCSharp-AzureToken");

            return client;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Could not create a graph client: " + ex.Message);
        }

        return client;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static async Task<string> GetTokenForUserAsync()
    {
        AuthenticationResult authResult;
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await IdentityClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
            IAccount firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

            authResult = await IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(Scopes, firstAccount);
            UserToken = authResult.AccessToken;
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (UserToken == null || Expiration <= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5))
            {
                authResult = await IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(Scopes );
                UserToken = authResult.AccessToken;
                Expiration = authResult.ExpiresOn;
            }
        }

        return UserToken;
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------
// Console entry point

class Program
{
    //public static GraphServiceClient client;
    public static HttpClient _client;

    static async Task<string> GetHttpResponse(string url)
    {
        string responseBody = null;
        _client = await AuthenticationHelper.GetAuthenticatedHttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            logger.Trace(responseBody);
        }

        return responseBody;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // call 1 is working: list groups that "are Microsoft Teams"
        string s;
        string url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/any(v:v eq 'Team')&$select=id,displayname,groupTypes,resourceBehaviorOptions,resourceProvisioningOptions";
        s = await GetHttpResponse(url);
        Console.WriteLine(s);

        // call 2 is working: Display details of one of these groups 
        Console.Write($"Enter the id of the group/teams to search for: ");
        string groupId = Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToLower();
        url = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{groupId}";
        s = await GetHttpResponse(url);
        Console.WriteLine(s);

        // call 3 is failing: Display the team view of this groups 
        url = url + "/team";
        s = await GetHttpResponse(url);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a scope. You need to have `Group.Read.All` in order to [read a Group or Team](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/team_get).

Comment: I don't think so because it works for groups without it. Moreover the request for team detail is working with Graph Explorer without it.

Comment: Graph Explorer includes `Group.ReadWrite.All` by default. This is a superset of `Group.Read.All` so Graph Explorer does use this scope. You need to have one of these two scopes before you can call the `/team` endpoint.

Comment: You were definitely right: adding the Group.Read.All scope fixed the issue.I can even request the /beta/me/JoinedTeams... which is not working with Graph Explorer. One thing I still don't understand is: unless I missed it why is the Group.Read.All scope missing from the Fiddler trace when sniffing traffic from Graph Explorer ?